# Any differences between critical dimension/size and resolution for an optical objective?

Tags: optics, visible-light, microscopy

I were studying something about the diffraction limit for a microscope when i found this definition:

> For a focusing objective or for lithography applications, the smallest resolvable distance or the so-called critical dimension/size, respectively, is $CD=k_1\lambda/N_A.$

Of course I know the definition $R=0.61\lambda/N_A$ for the optical resolution, which, at least to me, seems to be pretty similar to the "critical dimension". But why to introduce $k_1$? Is it possible to make $k_1\neq0.61$ for an optical objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this formula is probably saying that several different criteria can be used to define resolution, *e.g.* the Rayleigh criterion gives $k_1=0.61$,  and that they all have different values of $k_1$. The formula is saying that, no matter which criterion you use, the dependence on wavelength and numerical aperture is always the same: proportional to the former, inversely proportional to the latter.

Given the context, it would not be surprising if the $k_1$ were a semi-empirical constant that is found to represent the minimum feature size that is readily achieved in current photolithography technology, *i.e.* it takes into account not only the diffraction limit, but the etching process as well.

Resolution is a vague concept and the resolution one achieves depends heavily on signal to noise.  Another criterion used for Gaussian beams measures the resolution and numerical aperture by the $1/e^2$ diameters of the point spread function in both untransformed space and Fourier space, respectively. By these criteria, the formula is $CD = 2 \lambda / (\pi\,NA)$ and $k_1 = 2/\pi$, which is rather close to the Rayleigh criterion value. I discuss these criteria more in [my answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/300484/26076).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I found it very useful. However, I think $ k_1$ may also be correlated to the light distribution on the aperture, which determine the diffraction figure. I have read that in lithography a ring-shaped illumination could give a smaller $k_1$, as $k_1 \approx 0.36$.
I wonder if a similar arrangement could be realized in microscopy...